# How to validate a YAML file in angular6

Tags: json, angular, ansible, yaml, angular6

Lets say I have a yaml file which I want to validate in Angular6. If yaml file is parsed in json or other format successfully then say it's a valid yaml file otherwise it's not.

I found javascript and java has the solution for this question ,  but I wanted to do it using angular6.Is it possible to parse using angular and validate it?

Comment: Why dont you use "YAML Lint" or "YAML-validator" npm package ?

Comment: FYI, yaml-validator uses js-yaml under the covers

Comment: Please pay a bit more attention to proper capitalization (especially of acronyms like YAML and JSON), and to proper punctuation (and in English you mostly have spaces *after* punctuation). That makes it easier to read (especially for non-native speakers), and understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure *WHY* you'd want to parse a .yml file from Angular (vs., say, a standalone NodeJS app).

But sure.

The easiest way is probably to add a 3rd party library to your Angular build project (`npm install --save`), then invoke it from your Angular app.

js-yaml is a good choice: https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-yaml

EXAMPLE CODE (nodeJS):

```
yaml = require('js-yaml');
fs   = require('fs');

// Get document, or throw exception on error
try {
  var doc = yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync('/home/ixti/example.yml', 'utf8'));
  console.log(doc);
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: The [recommended extension for YAML](https://yaml.org/faq.html) files is `.yaml`. It has been like that since September 2006. Does angular (still) not support the recommended` extension? If it does support `.yaml`, please update your answer or explain why it is necessary to go against the recommendation.